# Rails/Rspec: Testing delayed_job mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, delayed-job

Just wondering how to test that actionmailer requests are actually sent to the delayed_job que in rspec.

I would have assumed it was quite simple, but my delayed_job queue doesn't seem to be incrementing. Code below:

Controller:

```
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
      if @contact.save
        contactmailer = ContactMailer
        contactmailer.delay.contact_message(@contact)
        redirect_to(contacts_url)
      else
        render :action => "new"
      end
```

Spec:

```
  it "queues mail when a contact is created" do
    expectedcount = Delayed::Job.count + 1
    Contact.stub(:new).with(mock_contact()) { mock_contact(:save => true) }
    post :create, :contact => mock_contact
    expectedcount.should eq(Delayed::Job.count)
  end
```

Both before and after the call to the controller, the Delayed::Job.count returns 0. I've tried taking the conditional out of the controller, but I still can't get the delayed job count to increment.

Any suggestions appreciated - cheer

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can also test what the jobs will do by running them or turning off queuing.

Tweak config whenever you want (i.e. in a `before :each` block).

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false
```

or perform your saved jobs

```
Delayed::Worker.new.work_off.should == [1, 0]
```

I have been using this method happily for a while. For one thing, using the new `any_instance` support in RSpec, you can test your delayed methods effects directly. However, I've found tests that use `work_off` to be *slow*.

What I usually do now is:

```
mock_delay = double('mock_delay').as_null_object
MyClass.any_instance.stub(:delay).and_return(mock_delay)
mock_delay.should_receive(:my_delayed_method)
```

Then I have a separate spec for `my_delayed_method`. This is much faster, and probably better unit testing practice -- particularly for controllers. Though if you're doing request specs or other integration-level specs, then you probably still want to use `work_off`.

Comment: I like this way. Note that for completeness you should also (separately) test that delayed jobs are getting added to the delayed_jobs table.

Answer (score 16):

I think your mock object is somehow introducing an error -- it's hard to tell exactly how without seeing the definition of the `mock_contact` method.

In any case, you might try something along these lines:

```
  it "queues mail when a contact is created" do
    Contact.stub(:new) { mock_model(Contact,:save => true) }
    Delayed::Job.count.should == 0
    post :create, {}
    Delayed::Job.count.should == 1
  end
```

or the sexier version (*caveat: I always end up doing it the non-sexy way*):

```
  it "queues mail when a contact is created" do
    Contact.stub(:new) { mock_model(Contact,:save => true) }
    expect {
      post :create, {}
    }.to change(Delayed::Job.count).by(1)
  end
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also follow the convention (from [Railscast 275](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test)) of

```
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to.should == user.email
```

but instead do this:

```
    Delayed::Job.last.handler.should have_content(user.email)
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old, but here is my go at it:

Create a function expect_jobs

```
def expect_jobs n, time = nil
  expect(Delayed::Job.count).to eq(n)
  Timecop.travel(time) unless time.nil?
  successes, failures = Delayed::Worker.new.work_off
  expect(successes).to eq(n)
  expect(failures).to eq(0)
  expect(Delayed::Job.count).to eq(0)
  Timecop.travel(Time.now) unless time.nil?
end
```

Then simply call it before checking if the callback has done its job. eg:

```
it "sends a chapter to the admin user" do
  post :chapter_to_user, { chapter: @book.chapters.first}
  expect_jobs(1)
  SubscribeMailer.should have(1).delivery
  SubscribeMailer.deliveries.should have(1).attachment
end
```

This seems to work on my side, and allows me to run both my delayed jobs *and* my methods.

Answer (score 0):

@zetetic I think we have to pass block in change method here.

It shoulb be like this:

```
it "queues mail when a contact is created" do
Contact.stub(:new) { mock_model(Contact,:save => true) }
expect {
    post :create, {}
  }.to change { Delayed::Job.count }.by(1)
end
```