# Why are emails not getting in the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently in my development environment I am not seeing anything in the `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` table after `mail` is used.  Is there a setting I am missing?

config/environments/development.rb:
 `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`.

app/mailers/notifier.rb

```
def send_email(user)
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to our website!")
end
```

These are the tests I'm running:

```
When /^I signup$/ do
  visit signup_path
  @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
  fill_in "user_password", :with => @user.password
  click_button "Join now"
end

Then /^I should receive a confirmation email$/ do
  email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  email.subject.should == "Welcome to our website!"
end
```

Right now I get the following error for the `I should receive a confirmation email` step:
`undefined method subject for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a view for your mailer? how are you testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting says that email is nil. In other words, the deliveries.last method is returning nil because there are no emails in it.

There could be a number of reasons... I'm assuming that you are using cucumber as the testing mechanism?

**1. Verify that 'click_button' submits**

You could try to put puts or log statements. Make sure that when you run the cucumber feature, it actually prints. Sometimes these things don't work because the front-end logic doesn't work and the test is failing correctly. In other words, the controller endpoint you are expecting to be triggered isn't being triggered.

**2. Verify that 'send_email' is right - using a unit test**

Next, verify that you are actually sending email. Write a unit test to verify this works. This should be quick and easy to get going. Plenty of articles out there.

Lastly, not really related, but you might want to roll with [email-spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) which should provide some nice testing methods so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility might be that in config/environments/test.rb you have

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

but you have set

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

so changing to

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

made it work again in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, I know, but a couple things come to mind:

- You talk about the configuration of your development environment (`config/environments/development.rb`), but it's your test that isn't working.  Check `config/environments/test.rb` and maybe `config\application.rb`.
- I actually wanted to see the email array in my development environment, but it always returned nil in the console. I finally realized that because the array is just a memory object, not in the database, the console (`rails c`) can't see what's going on in the server (`rails s`). When I added `<%= ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count %>` to a view, I could immediately see the array getting populated in development.
- Another "I can't see that process from the console" situation arises if you are using a separate thread or task for sending emails. With `delayed_job`, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252375/550712) suggesting you can look at the job (not the actual email) using `Delayed::Job.last.handler`, which *does* look at the database so works across processes. However this only works while the job is still in the database, i.e. before a worker has processed it.

Answer (score 0):

After making the changes answered by @Dominik Steiner, if it still didn't work ,

another possibility might be that in config/initializers/mailer.rb, you should have :

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
```

Above was missing in my case and it worked now.